# Standalone "Uncaught" Alert on Chrome Console

Tags: javascript, html, session-storage

I'm new to coding in HTML, CSS, and JavaScript, so please forgive me if my code is messy and/or incorrect.

I'm trying to make a website that can help people who are feeling mentally down, and for the first page, I added an input box which asks for the user's name, which will then be read in the next page. For example, if I put "Henry", the next page should say "Hello, Henry!" To read the variable in the next page, I used sessionStorage and sessionStorage.getItem("inputVal"). But, for some reason, when I try to log the variable (inputVal) in the first page, the console gives an error that simply says "Uncaught" for a brief moment before clearing when loading to the next page. Then, when I try to log the inputVal on the next page, the console only prints "null". I have scoured numerous forms, but I could not find anything to fix my problem! Have I written the sessionStorage wrong, or is there something else I'm missing? Here is the code for my first file:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <title>Feel Happy</title>
</head>
<body>
    <b class="welcometofeelhappy">Welcome to FeelHappy :)</b>
    <input type="text", id="whatisyourname", placeholder="Please enter your name!", class="whatisyournameinput" required><br>
    <form action="pages/landing.html">
            <button class="startBtn", type="submit", id="btn1", onclick="getInputValue()"><h2 class="buttontext1">Let's Begin!</h2></button>
    </form>
    <script>
        function getInputValue(){
            var inputVal = document.getElementById("whatisyourname").value;
            console.log(inputVal)
            sessionStorage("inputVal", inputVal)
        }
    </script> 
</body>
</html>
```

And the code to the second file:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <button onclick="getName()" type="button">Click Me!!</button>

    <script>

        function getName() {
            var inputVal = sessionStorage.getItem("inputVal")
            console.log(inputVal)
        }
        
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Note: For testing purposes, I put a button to print the code in the console.

Answer (score -1):

`sessionStorage("inputVal", inputVal)` is not how you write things to the session store. `sessionStorage` itself is not a function, it's an object that provides methods, like `setItem`.

You need `sessionStorage.setItem("inputVal", inputVal)`.

In terms of debugging, your browser's console can almost certainly be configured to persist logs after page transitions, which will allow you to see error messages even after you navigate away from the page where the error occurred.